# 400 bad request while performing post request in ionic to magento 2 API

Tags: magento, ionic2, magento2

I am trying to make API call to magento2 using an ionic app. The http post request gives '400' response.

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Access-Control-Request-Method', 'POST');
headers.append('Keep-Alive', 'timeout=5, max=100');

headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
headers.append('Connection', 'Keep-Alive');

headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

var body = 'username=armaan&password=66519845122423Aa';


let body = {
"username" : "armaan",
"password" : "66519845122423Aa"
 };


this.http.post('http://localhost/magento/rest/default/V1/integration/admin/token/', JSON.stringify(body), {headers: headers})
.map(res => res.json())
.subscribe(data => {
console.log(data);
});
```

[Network response from chrome while doing ionic-serve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQAku.jpg)

While doing 'ionic-serve' instead of doing a POST request it does OPTIONS(shown in image).

Answer (score 0):

Finally got a solution. It was an issue with CORS. Follow the link:
[Using CORS](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)